# Delete primary index of a database table programmatically

Tags: abap, ddl, database-indexes, opensql

I need to delete a Primary key indexes on some database tables. Afterwards indexes will be re-created. Meanwhile some calculation will be performed.

I have following SQL Commands:

```
DROP INDEX "SAPSR3"."KNA1~0";
```

that are working correctly.

But once called within ABAP program:

```
EXEC SQL. 
  DROP INDEX SAPSR3.KNA1~0 
ENDEXEC.
```

The message "SQL error 911 occurred when executing Native SQL" has been raised.

I've also tried with:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'RSDG_KEY_INDEX_DEL' 
  EXPORTING 
    i_tablnm = lv_tblname. " containing "KNA1"
```

This also doesn't work.

Is there any FM or similar way to perform such activity?

I also tried:

```
EXEC SQL.
  DROP INDEX KNA1~0
ENDEXEC.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of deleting a primaty key a of a standard database table?

Comment: the `Exec SQL` command is for native DB commands. So was is a SQL error 911. Looks like a timeout on DB2.   I do wonder why you are try that in ABAP.  Do it directly using a DB client.   Dropping the index on the main customer table. Wow

Comment: It is for testing purposes over Oracle DB and will reach Test systems. Dropping will allow modification of the data (also data duplication) of a rows avoiding Primary key conflicts. Before creating back the Primary key indexes data will be adjusted in unique combination of primary keys to pass correctly. I can't describe more about the purpose rather asking about possibility to provide it within ABAP, Thanks

Comment: `EXEC SQL` is discouraged. Prefer ADBC instead. SQL error 911 of DB2 indicates a "deadlock or timeout". Do you have ongoing activity from prior statements in your report, such as async index updates after row insertion? Try using a secondary database connection instead of `DEFAULT`. What does `RSDG_KEY_INDEX_DEL` fail with?

Comment: Hi Florian. Thanks for your suggestion in using ADBC. It helped a lot. Case closed. Best regards mate !

Comment: @OrdinaryPerson could you please answer your own question with a minimal example using ADBC?

Comment: @konstantin
 To perform a query : l_res_ref = l_stmt_ref->execute_query( l_stmt ).
 To perform a statement : l_stmt_ref->execute_ddl( l_stmt ).

Now I'm dealing with the response from Query execution since i'm not working with DDIC registered tables, but with database on DB Level.

Highly recommend to check this report:
ADBC_DEMO

Regards

Answer (score 3):

What you tried, in the SQL console (`DROP INDEX "SAPSR3"."KNA1~0";`), and in the ABAP program (`DROP INDEX SAPSR3.KNA1~0`), are not written identically as you can see!

I have just tried in ABAP below the version that you tried in the SQL console, and it dropped the index as intended!

```
EXEC SQL.
  DROP INDEX "SAPSR3"."KNA1~0" 
ENDEXEC.
```

So, why, in your ABAP attempt, did you remove the double quotes around the index name? (and also for the scheme name, but I guess it has less undesired effect).

In the SQL console, I'm really not sure that `DROP INDEX SAPSR3.KNA1~0` works! Because there is the special "tilde" character, you need to add double quotes around the index name, the following is the minimal working syntax: `DROP INDEX SAPSR3."KNA1~0"`.